# Equivalent statement of an at most countable set is closed under set union

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I'm not sure the following is true.

Let $\mathbb S$ be an at most countable familiy of sets whose every element is a member of $T$. Then the following statement holds.
$$\forall \mathbb{S}\subseteq T: |\mathbb{S}|\leq\aleph_0\rightarrow\bigcup\mathbb{S}\in T\iff \forall X,Y\in T:X\cup Y\in T$$

I am studying topology alone as a hobby, and currently studying about the very foundation. I've just made up this unsure statement while thinking about one of the axioms of topology, but my proving skill is not good enough to prove it. How should I prove or disprove the statement?

Comment: Is $T$ a topology on a set? If so, then this is true by definition. If these are closed sets of the topological space, then this is not true.

Comment: You cannot say "Let $\mathbb S$ be ..." and then follow up with a formula where $\mathbb S$ is bound by a quantifier. When the variable letter $\mathbb S$ is not free in the formula, the surrounding prose _does not get to decide_ what it means.

Comment: @Henning Makholm : Yes. Should I add the properties of $\mathbb{S}$ as a condition in the left hand side of the formula? It's going to be long, though.

Comment: @Amateur: Yes, that is probably what you mean. You can also say that the variable letter $\mathbb S$ _ranges over_ at most countable families of etc. etc.